# R Highcharter Drilldown Set Ymin & Ymax + Title for each layer

Tags: r, highcharts, drilldown

I am currently working with the java script wrapper highcharter in R. 
I would like to manually set the Y axis for each of the layer, as well as the title for each layer but have not been able to find a way to do so.

E.g the title for all layers are currently "Basic Drilldown", and i would like to update this for each of the drilldowns. As well as I would like to manually set the y axis.

Thanks in advance.

Current code below.

```
df <- data_frame(
  name = c("Animals", "Fruits", "Cars"),
  y = c(5, 2, 4),
  drilldown = tolower(name)
)

df

hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Basic drilldown") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      boderWidth = 0,
      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = df,
    name = "Things",
    colorByPoint = TRUE
  )


dfan <- data_frame(
  name = c("Cats", "Dogs", "Cows", "Sheep", "Pigs"),
  value = c(4, 3, 1, 2, 1)
)

dffru <- data_frame(
  name = c("Apple", "Organes"),
  value = c(4, 2)
)

dfcar <- data_frame(
  name = c("Toyota", "Opel", "Volkswagen"),
  value = c(4, 2, 2)
)

hc <- hc %>%
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "animals",
        data = list_parse2(dfan)
      ),
      list(
        id = "fruits",
        data = list_parse2(dffru)
      ),
      list(
        id = "cars",
        data = list_parse2(dfcar)
      )
    )
  )

hc
```

EDIT* updated with answer to dynamically set yaxis for R highcharts.

```
      drilldown =  JS('function(e) {
 console.log(e.seriesOptions);
          this.setTitle({text: e.seriesOptions.name || e.seriesOptions.id });
          this.yAxis[0].update({ min: this.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max * 0.5 })}')
```

Comment: I've done some more research and figured i need to call a java script function in the title argument.
So far I have tried   
hc_title(text = JS("function(){return e.seriesOptions.name;}")) %>%, but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to refactor your code a bit, because it's not correct. For example, try to create new variable with all series names and assign this list of names to `drilldown` field in your `data.frame`:

```
names <- c("Animals", "Fruits", "Cars")

df <- data.frame(
  name = names,
  y = c(5, 2, 4),
  drilldown = names
)
```

Then, change the drilldown `id`'s in your drilldown object definition, because it's not necessary to make them start from lowercase:

```
hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(
        id = "Animals",
        data = list_parse2(dfan)
      ),
      list(
        id = "Fruits",
        data = list_parse2(dffru)
      ),
      list(
        id = "Cars",
        data = list_parse2(dfcar)
      )
    )
  )
```

The final step is defining the `chart.events.drilldown` and `chart.events.drillup` function handlers, inside of which you will set the `chart.title.text` using `Chart.update()` function. In order to define it, you have to use `JS()` R built-in function, just like below:

```
hc_chart(type = "column", events = list(
    load = JS("function() {console.log(this)}"),
    drilldown = JS("function(e) {this.update({title: {text: e.seriesOptions.id}})}"),
    drillup = JS("function() {this.update({title: {text: 'Basic drilldown' }})}")
  )) %>%
```

Actually, i don't quite understand this part of the question:

> As well as I would like to manually set the y axis.

If you describe it more precisely then I will extend the answer.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, this works perfectly. I have updated the question with additional information for the axis request. 
Thank you kindly!!

Comment: Hi Daniel, 
I figured out an answer to my request but have one additional question. 
I have updated my code with the axis solution, however I have a combination of graphs in my final drilldown and would like to only apply the axis to all "column" graphs. If the graph is a line graph I would just like highcharts to autoformat. Thankful for any help.